# How to change address bar color in google chrome PC

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to change color of address bar in Chrome(PC)?
Currently I have white one but I would like to have black one with white text in it. Is that possible to change?

This is how it looks now: 
[Chrome Address bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVs26.jpg)

And this is how I would like it to look:

[Chrome Address bar in incognito mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyEAL.jpg)

Comment: Alas, you can't change that without building your own patched Chromium.

Comment: You could download a theme with a black address bar, or perhaps make your own theme with just that alteration.  Yeah, just tried. 'Morpheon Dark' is the top theme, which is all-black, and free, and installs in a split second.

Comment: @Davesoft I dont know why, but all Dark themes have white address bar.

Comment: I already tried doing that but I could not change the color of address bar in my custom theme, that's why I am asking if there is any workaround since in incognito mode you have nice dark address bar.

Comment: Looks like one more reason to love chrome, apart from irremovable crosses on tabs and animations that you can't disable and have to endure looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Simple Material Theme for chrome:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-material-theme/mdnphgdednjnpcoeamekbogoblkdajep

In the new update they added dark address bar.(Chrome version: 75.0.3770.142)

It looks like this:
[image]